# Identifying Bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, bifurcation

I am trying to identify bifurcation of my $3D$ system near $a=6.58$. I am getting trajectories as shown in the picture and I am guessing it is Saddle-Node periodic orbit bifurcation since I am getting periodic trajectories around a saddle point. Is my guess alright?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHBAm.jpg)